# Delayed cold start report in AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Consider the following AWS Lambda function:

```py
import json
import time
import pickle

def ms_now():
    return int(time.time_ns() / 1000000)

class Timer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = ms_now()

    def stop(self):
        return ms_now() - self.start

timer = Timer()
started_init = ms_now()
cold_start = True
init_time = timer.stop()

... # Some heavy machine learning models are loaded here

def compute(event):
    ... # The actual computation is here

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    global cold_start
    global init_time
    global started_init
    
    stats = {'cold_start': cold_start,
             'started_init': started_init,
             'init_time': init_time}
    cold_start = False
    init_time = 0
    started_init = 0

    stats['started'] = ms_now()
    result = compute(event)
    stats['finished'] = ms_now()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'result': result, 
        'stats': stats
    }
```

The `stats` returned as part of the response has fields that show whether a cold start has occurred and, if so, when the initialization of global variables began and how long it took.

Another Lambda function calls the one above, processes the `stats` in the response and adds a row to the output string:

```py
started = stats['started'] - exec_begin    # exec_begin is the timestamp just before above AWS Lambda is invoked.
init = stats['init_time']
if init > 0:
    started_init_str = f"started_init: {stats['started_init'] - exec_begin}   "
else:
    started_init_str = ""
time = stats['finished'] - stats['started']
now = ms_now() - exec_begin
globals.worker_trace += (
    f"{job['description']}-{job['id']}   cold: {stats['cold_start']}   {started_init_str}init: {init}ms   started: {started}   time: {time}ms   now: {now}\n")
```

I tested this latter function manually from the web console about every 3 minutes. For a warm start, the output is like this:

```
cold: False   init: 0ms   started: 239   time: 96ms   now: 408
```

The weird thing happens when a cold start occurs:

```
cold: True   started_init: -184189   init: 6852ms   started: 101   time: 169ms   now: 408
```

**Question 1.** How does `started_init` end up negative as if the cold start occurred during the previous run? CloudWatch shows the the cold start occurs during the current one.

**Question 2.** Both the invocation that reports the cold start with the initialization time of over six seconds and the previous invocation return a response in under half-a-second. So, when does this cold-start initialization actually take place?

P.S. The [question at re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUuZwcXVPsQ1Gbwg2ugsZ8eA/delayed-cold-start-report-in-aws-lambda-function)